# execution plan for view vastly different than for query (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, view, sql-execution-plan

Is there any reason a query plan for a view would differ vastly from that for just the query used to build the view?

We had a query that was executing very quickly, but after creating a view, using the same query, the performance dropped significantly when the code was changed to use the view instead of executing the query. We found the execution plans to be drastically different.

Comment: My wild guess would be that some predicate isn't getting pushed correctly https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/entry/basics_of_join_predicate_pushdown_in_oracle .  May be using a hammer to swat a fly, but I'd be looking at the secure_view_merging parameter http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/initparams162.htm unless you're using VPD http://antognini.ch/2011/09/optimizer_secure_view_merging-and-vpd/

Comment: Is there anything in the "Notes" section of the execution plans?  It's possible that some type of plan management feature was only applied to one of the queries.  For example, there could be a profile, SQL Plan Baseline, outline, advanced rewrite directive, VPD, patch, etc.